# Symfony2 Class is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm new to symfony2 and trying to execte the command in neatbeans

```
console doctrine:generate:entities /backend/storeBundle/Entity/RolClass
```

it's shown the error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
Class "\backend\storeBundle\Entity\RolClass" is not a valid entity or 
mapped super class.
```

The class:

```
<?php
namespace backend\storeBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="nomrol")
*/
  class RolClass {
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
 */
protected $namerolcust;
}
```

Searching info in this page I tried to modify the app/config.yml:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                backendstoreBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it is bad practice to use CLass in you class name, please remove ;)

1) do the above an then re-run

2) If that still fails then for some reason then alter you config.yml to

```
     orm:
         auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
         auto_mapping: true
```

Now if that fails for some strange reason you doctrine is looking for a superclass so you will have to do the following.

*Define the base-class:*

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseRol
{
    // base rol
}
```

*Then extend your class*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rol extends Baserol
{
    // rol
}
```

Because you're missing the @MappedSuperclass annotation on the base-class, Doctrine throws the exception you mention.

Comment: I made the modifications the error changes to `[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                      
  Class "\backend\entityBundle\Entity\Rolname" sub class of "backend\entityBundle\Entity\Baseent" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

Comment: OK this is really odd, as you have just started delete these two entities. Lets start again (sometimes is the best option). The problem could be netbeans lets try a terminal, are you using a MAC, Windows or Virtual machine such as UBUNTU?

Comment: I'm using windows 7. And I strated again more than 5 times.

Comment: OK cool, open up your termial, run the following.

cd toYourDocumentfolder //////

php app/console doctrine:generate:entity

fill in and complete what happends next?

Comment: I see that is an error from netbeans. If you execute in comand line it works. Thanks

Comment: Cool beans, glad I could help

Comment: I made a mistake. `doctrine:generate:entities` is not the same that `doctrine:generate:entity`. If I execute the first option the result is the same. But I think taht I could use the second option for create my entity class.